# create meshed rectangle from its vertex values in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, mesh, vertex

I am facing some problem in creating the meshed rectangle. I know the max and min coordinate values (`xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax`, `zmin`, `zmax`). So, I can easily find the vertex of the rectangle which are

```
[xmin ymin zmin; 
 xmax ymin zmin; 
 xmax ymax zmin; 
 xmin ymax zmin;
 xmin ymin zmax; 
 xmax ymin zmax; 
 xmax ymax zmax;
 xmin ymax zmax]
```

Now how can I create the rectangle with the surface mesh?

Comment: Do you mean that you want a 3D cube?

Comment: yes, a 3D cube/rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a [`patch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html?refresh=true) in which you define [vertices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch-properties.html#property_vertices) and the [patch faces](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch-properties.html#property_faces). For a rectangular prism, you can create your vertices and faces in the following way:

```
[xx,yy,zz] = ndgrid([xmin, xmax], [ymin, ymax], [zmin zmax]);
vertices = [xx(:), yy(:), zz(:)];

% Each row corresponds to a face of the prism and the values are indices into vertices
faces = [1     2     6     5
         2     4     8     6
         4     3     7     8
         3     1     5     7
         1     2     4     3
         5     6     8     7];

p = patch('Faces', faces, ...
          'Vertices', vertices, ...
          'FaceColor', [0, 0.4470, 0.7410], ...
          'FaceAlpha', 0.2);                        % Set transparency so we can see it
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help!!!! But I need the surface mesh also. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @galib What format are you looking for? Technically the `faces` and `vertices` above compose a surface mesh

Comment: @ Suever ...something like this.... http://nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/~fangq/temp/testmesh.png.                                 or is it possible to use pdetoolbox to generate this kind of meshing. I know how to generate mesh using pdetool for .stl files. But here, I can't use .stl files, that's the problem.